Are the steps in my solution for this BJT circuit correct?
I am faced with this question:

Calculate and determine the value of the resistor RE that will ensure that VC=6 V.
Redraw the transistor model of the equivalent circuit for small amplitude AC signals. Determine the voltage gain Av of the circuit.


I solved the question as follows ;
VB = [24K / 24K+82K] x 16V = 3,62 Volt
RB = 24Kx82K / 24k+82k = 18,56K
6 = 16 - ICx5,6k
Ic = 1,78mA
IC = ßxIb = 150xIb
Ib = 11,86 microampere
IE = 11,86x10^-6 x 151 = 1,79mA
re = 26mV / 1,79mA = 14,5
VB - VBE - IBxRB - IExRE = 0
3,62 - 0,7 - [ (11,86 x 10^6) x 18,56K ] - 1,79mA x RE = 0
RE = 402K
Av = -ß x Rc / ßre + (ß+1)RE
Av = -150 x 5600 / 2,175 + 0 (The reason why it is 0 is because the Re resistor and capacitor are in parallel, I know that it is an ineffective element in AC analysis.)
This is my solution.  Are my solution steps correct? If I made a mistake when converting units, can you warn me? I need to correct my shortcomings and learn the right way.
EDITED:
We determined that the Re resistor was wrong and corrected it. I would like to thank @Antonio51 for this.

Approximately, RE= (3.62-0.7-11.9u*18.56k)/1.78m=1.516 k

Why didn`t you start with the given value Vc=6V ? This will give you the starting point for Ic and Ie. Starting with Ib is a false approach.

solve([Eq(vb/82e3+vb/24e3+ib,16/82e3),Eq((vb-0.7)/re,151*ib),Eq(150*ib,(16-6)/5.6e3)],[ib,re,vb]) gives [(1.19047619047619e-5, 1502.88641759340, 3.40161725067385)]. Many approaches with this problem.

@Antonio51 , When I do what you do, I find a negative value, I find a value like -122, I can't find 1.516k. where am I wrong?

11.9u*18.56k=0.221

You have to be very careful with unit conversions. Since you wrote it directly, you did not write the unit conversion, you did a quick operation, I found it by trying it myself, now I understand, thanks @Antonio51

My units are ok. Did you read it correctly?

yes, I read it, but I meant that it needs to be transformed between units :)

Do you see anything wrong with the calculation of Av?
You know that we calculate Av for AC analysis @Antonio51

Numerically, the antonio51 formula is correct. Why are you having problems with it I wonder?

@Andyaka , antonio's formula is completely correct, I'm not saying it's wrong, I just wanted to draw attention to the point about transformations while doing operations, that's all :)

No worries. I have a "good" calculator with microcap v12 https://gotroot.ca/spectrum/www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.html...

Made with microcap v12. Circuit interactively adjusted.
The gain is approximately - 385 = - Ic / VT* Rc ...
Calculus with your values is made within the file circuit (low of page).
Some voltages are somewhat "different" because of the "beta" of BJT.


Thank you very much,
So, is there a mistake here? Is there a wrong value or unit conversion or something about RE being shorted in the AC state of the circuit or apart from all that, is there anything I should know about the points to be considered when calculating Av or are all my steps here correct?
note: RE is shorted in AC analysis because it is connected in parallel with the capacitor, so (ß+1)RE = 0
-ß x Rc / ßre + (ß+1)RE = -150 x 5600 / 2,175 + 0 = -386,206
Is all this true?

Avo=- gmRc =-(1/26m)*icRc = -(1/26m)1.78m5.6k = ~ 380 ... Note that with the load, I have ~ -300.

gm parameters are the subject of jfet, I am talking about bjt here. i.e. the question in the picture

gm can also be used with BJT. page 24 and 31 https://ee.eng.usm.my/eeacad/laili/241/L3.pdf

hmm I see, so what I did when I opened the thread is correct?

Calculation by hand:
Ic=(16-6)/5.6k=1.79mA and Ie=1.79+0.009=1.8mA
with (assumption): Ib=1.79mA/200=~9µA
Base voltage Vb=(16-I1R1)=[16-(I2+Ib)R1] with I2=Vb/R2
Vb=(16-82k*9µ)/(1+3.4)=3.47V   with R1/R2=3.4
Re=(Vb-0.7)/Ie=1.54k
ADDED LATER:
The small signal gain is simply Av=-gmRc (neglecting the large internal transistor output resistance re=1/h22).
The transconductance is determined by the collector current gm=Ic/VT (Vt=~26mV)

And what can you say about the hunt, do you see any mistakes there?

I ccannot see how you arrive at RE. This resistor is simply RE=Ve/Ie with Ve=VB-0.7V.
